# Export multiple Graphics3D objects combined using Show in a single 3d format file

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, export

Suppose I have two (or multiple) `Graphics3D` objects that I am displaying together using `Show`:

```
data=Show[obj1, obj2]
```

The output of this `Show` command is another `Graphics3D` object.

But if I try to export this object in a 3d format, say in ply format:

```
Export["data.ply", data]
```

, then only `obj1` is getting exported in the file.

How do I export both `obj1` and `obj2` in a single .ply file?

Comment: It is possible that `obj2` contains primitives that *Mathematica* is not able to export. Did you check that `obj2` on its own is exportable?

Comment: Ah! So not everything that can be rendered in Mathematica is exportable? Let me check.

Comment: @J.M. You are partially right. My `obj2` is a combination of `Triangle` primitives and outputs from `ParametricPlot3D`. Only the `Triangle`s are getting exported. Why is that?

Comment: I have a correction. If I use .ply or .obj formats, then only the `Triangle`s are getting exported. If I use .stl format, then the `ParametricPlot3D` outputs are also getting exported!

Comment: Could you please point me to a resource for understanding which file format supports what? And possibly, which formats support export colouring information? I only know of this one page: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/3DGeometryAndModelingFormats.html